# If (gender)=boy or girl

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do an or in an if statement what I've got is:

```
var gender = prompt("are you a boy or a girl?");

if(gender==="boy"/"girl")
{
    console.log("sex:  "+gender);
}
else
{
    throw "you must select boy or girl";
```

I put the / there thinking it might make it boy or girl, I have tried everything.

Comment: `if(gender==="boy" || gender==="girl")`

Comment: should be like this: if ( gender === 'boy' || gender === 'girl' )

Comment: There is a bracket missing

Comment: Surprised no one has answered `["boy", "girl"].indexOf(gender) !== -1`

Comment: If someone is so new to JavaScript they are confused about the basic OR syntax then this would be a little too technical for them to understand: hence what they will do is to memorize it as it is and start copy pasting it for their future needs without understanding. Therefore a basic OR was considered better while answering

Comment: ^ I am very new to JavaScript. I've been learning for about a week but I've never had to use this command before. Thanks for understanding Hanky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(gender=="boy" || gender=="girl")
{
    console.log("sex:  "+gender);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression, why don't you? :-)

```
if (/^(boy|girl)$/i.test(gender))
...
```

Comment: Because RegEx is overkill.

Comment: Most people don't like wasting CPU

Comment: This is not how you should teach someone new to Javascript how to "do an or in an if statement".

Comment: I think the real question is how should you teach someone new to javascript to do input validation.  I think this is a nice, easy introduction to regular expressions as well...  Also there's a smiley there - should be one of these instead? :-P

Comment: I upvoted this answer. I use this all the time, probably not with just two options, but a useful answer nonetheless. Btw, you don't need the capturing group, you can just do `/boy|girl/`

Comment: Thanks, elclanrs - I'm just in the habit of using parentheses to separate from larger expressions.

Comment: @Paulpro That doesn't mean you shouldn't provide what's been used before and works. You shouldn't just read specifically what the text in the question is. The OP is clearly trying to achieve something - and this is an option that does that. The fact that the OP is new makes this even a better idea - the regex is simple and it's for a simple scenario. Although I'd say it could be explained more. There's already several answers with the "real" answer - using `||`, so why shouldn't this be included?

Comment: @EricMickelsen: Latest edit makes sense, otherwise we would be matching `boys` as well. Nice catch.

Answer (score 3):

What you also need to consider is case-sensitivity. If you need to ignore case-sensitivity, you can do:

```
if(gender.toLowerCase() === "boy" || gender.toLowerCase() === "girl")
    console.log("sex:  " + gender);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `||`

```
if(gender === 'boy' || gender === 'girl'){
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

You can also do a `switch`

```
switch(gender){
  case 'boy':
  case 'girl':
    ...
    break;
  default:
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [logical or operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) in Javascript is `||`. Use it like this:

```
if(gender === "boy" || gender === "girl")
{
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use logical or (||) operator in JavaScript .As you are new to JavaScript , learning these  [logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) .. basic OR (||), basic AND (&&) ... are first step.

```
if ( gender == 'boy' || gender == 'girl' ){
    console.log("sex:  " + gender);
};
```

I made some other options for learning purpose for you ...  some are dirty . I hope following code, make you interest in advance JavaScript . Now I suggest you don't look deep into it, once you are excellent in basic's of JavaScript. check the following and how they works

Use array [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), which Implemented in JavaScript 1.6

```
if ( ["boy", "girl"].indexOf(gender) !== -1 ){
    console.log("sex:  " + gender);
};
```

Using regular expressions , link of [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```
if ( /boy|girl/i.test( gender ) ){
    console.log("sex:  " + gender);
};
```

Using  [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) mapper , `!!` converts into boolean

```
if ( !!{ boy:true, girl:true}[gender]  ){
    console.log("sex:  " + gender);
};
```

There may be other ways .. :)